# Print only a single slash using print r"\" (Python)

Tags: python, format

I want to print a single slash using `print r` in Python.
For example:

```
print r"heythere\"
```

But this line gives an error. But if you put anything after that slash it will be printed, for example: 
`print r"heythere\hey"`

What I did wrong, how can I print slash?
I don't want to use anything else, only working with print r" ".

Comment: `print("heythere\\")`

Comment: I want to use raw string only. Please use only print r" "

Comment: It's a limitation of the way `r""` strings were implemented in Python's parser - there *must* be a character after the \.

Comment: Why do you want to use only raw string?